# Неправильно отображается верстка на GitHub Pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, github-pages

Добрый день подскажите пожалуйста, я сверстал страничку и залил ее на GitHub Pages. На локальном сервере все смотрится годно, однако на гитхабе все слетает непонятно как. Подскажите как решить проблему?

[Ссылка на страничку на GitHub Pages](https://krionix.github.io/myDemo/)

Comment: Проверьте все ли у вас подключено. Я имею ввиду фреймворки если такие имеются и т. д.  jQuery судя по рабочему слайдеру подключен и работает.

Comment: откройте консоль, там половина файлов не подключена,` _main.css` стоит заменить на просто `main.css` так же и все остальные файлы, проверить пути, имена файлов

Comment: Нужны ли вам все библиотеки в папке `/libs`? Такое количество будет лишь замедлять работу. Там у многих дублирующиеся функции. Пересмотрите, может получиться оптимизировать как-то, что-то вообще убрать. Но это лишь мое мнение. У вас своя задумка. Просто обратите на это внимание.

Comment: Огромное всем спасибо!!! Проблема решилась, благодаря вам)

Answer (score 4):

По умолчанию GitHub Pages не обрабатывает файлы, начинающиеся с нижнего подчёркивания. [В документации](https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing/) предлагается три решения этой проблемы:

- не использовать файлы, начинающиеся с нижнего подчёркивания
- добавить файл `.nojekyll` в корневую папку сайта
- использовать директиву `include` в файле `_config.yml` чтобы Jekyll не игнорировал эти файлы